# Converting UNIX time

Tags: python, beginner, datetime

I have crated the following small script.  I just need to improve this complicated code if possible.

```
def convUnixTime(t):
    expr_date = int(t) * 86400
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    d1 = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    d2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(expr_date)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, fmt)
    d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2, fmt)
    return (d2-d1).days
```

Comment: What is your reason to do `strftime` followed by `strptime`?

Comment: new to python.. don't know much.. just created from googling.. :D

Comment: What does this function even do?

Comment: On *nix Server it's required to Convert Unix timestamp to Readable Date/time, I used this function to check User account expiry date..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the main issue here is that you are trying to reuse snippets from Google without trying to understand what is doing what.

**Magic numbers**

This might be purely personal but I find `60*60*24` much easier to understand than `86400`.

**Do not repeat yourself**

What is the point of having `fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` if later on you rewrite `strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` ? You could write it : `d1 = datetime.date.today().strftime(fmt)` making obvious to everyone that the same format is used.

**Useless conversion between strings and dates**

You are converting dates to string and string to date in a convoluted and probably not required way.

**Usess conversion to int**

You are using `int(expr_date))` but `expr_date` is defined as `int(t) * 86400` which is an integer anyway. Also, I am not sure you would need the conversion of `t` as an int.

Taking into account the different comments, my resulting not-tested code looks like :

```
def convUnixTime(t):
        return (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(t*60*60*24)
              - datetime.datetime.today()).days
```

**Edit** : I was using `datetime.date.today()` instead of `datetime.datetime.today()`. Also fixed the sign issue.

Comment: I have tested it is giving error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.date' and 'datetime.datetime'`

Comment: Arg! I'll try and think about a proper working solution then :-P

Comment: If `t` is already in seconds, then that is what `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` is expecting, you don't want to do any arithmetic with it. Also, the returned `datetime.datetime` object has no `days` member. If you meant the `day` member, it is the day of the month, not the number of days.

Comment: I've fixed the code and it seems to be behaving just like yours (not sure if good thing or bad thing).

Comment: Thanks Josay for your help.. I saw.. my lazyness in small mistakes.. I will not repeat that again..

Comment: not it's working but, it -1 one day, why ? means today date is 13 Jun and act will expr on 15 Jun , so days should be 2 but it's showing 1, why ?

Comment: What value of t are you testing with?